# How to get weekending having all approved records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table like below

```
date      |    weekending   |    isapproved

2/17/2020     2/23/2020            0
2/18/2020     2/23/2020            1
2/19/2020     2/23/2020            0
2/20/2020     2/23/2020            0
2/27/2020     3/1/2020             1
2/26/2020     3/1/2020             1
2/28/2020     3/1/2020             1
3/4/2020      3/8/2020             0
3/5/2020      3/8/2020             1
3/5/2020      3/8/2020             1
```

now want to get weekending '3/1/2020' since it have all 1's in isApproved like this I want to get list of weekending having all 1's in isApproved

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't it work? What is your question? What are your expected results? "I want" isn't a question, what is it you're asking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select weekending
from mytable
group by weekending
having min(isapproved) = 1
```

This works because `isapproved` only has `0/1` values. So condition `min(isapproved) = 1` actually ensures that there is no `0` value.

Comment: If `isapproved` is a `BIT`, you will need to convert it before you can do `MIN`, e.g. `MIN(CONVERT(TINYINT, isapproved)) = 1`